# Unit Testing Components

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I've spent the last 24 hours trying to build a unit test around one of my EmberJS components. I'm using qunit. I'd like to test the entire component (handlebars template and all) as one distinct unit.

My component looks like this:

```
App.MyAwesomeComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  someAttribute: null
  someComputedValue: function() {
    this.get('someAttribute') + ' some extra piece of text ';
  }.property('someAttribute')
});
```

The components/my-awesome-component.handlebars file looks like this:

```
{{someComputedValue}}
```

...and the test looks like this:

```
test("When passed a string after rendering, renders the computed value as its content", function() {
  component = App.MyAwesomeComponent.create({
    templateName: "components/my-awesome"
  });
  appendComponentToView();
  component.set('someAttribute', 'an exciting value');
  var result = view.$().text().trim();
  equal(result, "an exciting value some extra piece of text ", "contents are rendered with the new value in place");
});
```

The problem is I keep getting various errors such as "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'depth0['my-awesome']') and the like.

I'm searching for some kind of golden path for unit testing components. I don't want to use an integration test (for hopefully obvious reasons - it's a component and I don't want to build a dummy page in my app just so I can test it from various angles).

The documentation on the ember site is severely lacking when it comes to unit testing, and all my websearches have turned up naught useful for what seems to me to be the standard case for unit testing components.

Thanks in advance! :)

Julian

Comment: does `components/my-awesome-component.handlebars` actually inject the template named `components/my-awesome` or does it inject it as `components/my-awesome-component` ?

Comment: I don't know. Not sure how I could tell. This is a similar problem to the one you just answered... I couldn't work out how to simply test components with their templates (I orignally didn't know you had to specify the template and that the testing env didn't auto-glue it together like normal non-testing ember does).

Comment: I can probably just close this question, tho it does still raise the issue of their being little to no documented golden path of how to do unit testing on the ember site. Not sure what to do when I don't really need a question answered anymore?

Comment: Good idea. Will do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working by utilising the runloop.

```
test("When passed a string after rendering, renders the computed value as its content", function() {
  component = App.MyAwesomeComponent.create({
    layoutName: "components/my-awesome"
  });
  appendComponentToView();
  Ember.run(function() {
    component.set('someAttribute', 'an exciting value');
  });
  var result = view.$().text().trim();
  equal(result, "an exciting value some extra piece of text ", "contents are rendered with the new value in place");
});
```

The reason it works is the runloop forces the bit inside to evaluate at precisely that point in the code so that the binding has updated the template by the time the var result = ... line executes.

Hope that saves someone else some anguish.